# Modify the Progress<T> callback Action

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Say I have the following struct:

```
public struct TaskWithProgress<TResult>
{
    public Task<TResult> Task { get; set; }
    public IProgress<double> Progress { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public CancellationTokenSource CancelTokenSource { get; set; }
}
```

I wish to be able to create this struct anywhere in my code, and allow the `Task` to report `Progress`. However the action to perform when the progress is reported resides in one form (updating a progress bar). Typically I would use the progress property like so:

```
Progress = new Progress<double>(x => pb.Position = Convert.ToInt32(100 * x));
```

Is there a way I can create this `IProgress<T>` from the client code, then subscribe to the Report() callback later?

**EDIT**
I could use the concrete implementation and use the ProgressChanged event... but then I can't call the Report() method of IProgress. What is the way forward here?

Answer (score 1):

Just subclass `Progress<T>` with a new class that exposes the `Report(T value)` method and use that concrete class instead.

```
public  class ReportingProgress<T> : Progress<T>, IProgress<T>
{
    public ReportingProgress()
    {
    }

    public ReportingProgress(Action<T> handler)
        : base(handler)
    {
    }

    public void Report(T value)
    {
        this.OnReport(value);
    }
}
```

This is exactly the same thing the normal `Progress<T>` class does, here is the code for it's `Report()` method, gotten from the .NET reference source.

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
void IProgress<T>.Report(T value)
{
  this.OnReport(value);
}
```